# Can't get nested async functions inside .map() to run before .then() block

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am building a script which is to generate a report on subscriptions. The following explains the process:

```
First Request: get all subscriptions (includes truncated subscriber list)
Second Request: loop through response, fetch complete recipient list for each subscription

Result: Compile report by collated all of the data into a single array
```

Problem here is that since I am using `await, Promise & async` in my code (required by tool) the CSV begins building **after** the bulk GET but **before** the GET's from recipients of each individual subscription.

As a result, I get a list of only 600 (total amount of subscriptions) when it should in fact be over 6,000 (all subs plus all of the recipients)

How do I reconstruct this such that the function `util.buildCSV()` doesn't start running until all data is returned and pushed into the `report` array?

Important to note that all of the request functions are async and can only run in an async function themselves, which makes this rather annoying and difficult.

CODE:

```
const fields = [
  'sub_name',
  'sub_uuid',
  'form_name',
  'form_id',
  'plan_name',
  'plan_id',
  'owner_targetName',
  'owner_firstName',
  'owner_lastName',
  'owner_uuid',
  'applications',
  'lob'
];

(async (env) => {
  const report        = []
  const subscriptions = await xm.subscriptions.getMany(env);

  await Promise.all(subscriptions.map(sub => {
    let apps_and_lobs = xm.subscriptions.process_apps_and_lobs(sub.criteria.data);
    let sub_obj = {
      sub_name         : sub.name,
      sub_uuid         : sub.id,
      form_name        : sub.form.name,
      form_id          : sub.form.id,
      plan_name        : sub.form.plan.name,
      plan_id          : sub.form.plan.id,
      owner_targetName : sub.owner.targetName,
      owner_firstName  : sub.owner.firstName,
      owner_lastName   : sub.owner.lastName,
      owner_uuid       : sub.owner.id,
      applications     : apps_and_lobs.apps,
      lob              : apps_and_lobs.lobs
    };

    report.push(sub_obj);

    if (sub.recipients && sub.recipients.count > 1) {
      (async (env) => {
        let recipients = await xm.subscriptions.getSubscribers(env, null, sub.id);
        recipients.map(r => {
          let recip_obj = {
            sub_name         : sub.name,
            sub_uuid         : sub.id,
            form_name        : sub.form.name,
            form_id          : sub.form.id,
            plan_name        : sub.form.plan.name,
            plan_id          : sub.form.plan.id,
            owner_targetName : r.targetName,
            owner_firstName  : r.firstName,
            owner_lastName   : r.lastName,
            owner_uuid       : r.id,
            applications     : apps_and_lobs.apps,
            lob              : apps_and_lobs.lobs
          };

          report.push(recip_obj);
          console.log(`> ${report.length}`);  // runs after the below COMPLETE > console log showing its breaking in async
        })
      })(env)
    } else {
      console.log(`> ${report.length}`);
    }
  })).then((thing) => {
    util.cmt(`COMPLETE > ${report.length}`);
    util.buildCSV(fields, report, 'subscriptions_dev', true);
  })
})(prod);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const fields = [
  'sub_name',
  'sub_uuid',
  'form_name',
  'form_id',
  'plan_name',
  'plan_id',
  'owner_targetName',
  'owner_firstName',
  'owner_lastName',
  'owner_uuid',
  'applications',
  'lob'
];

(async (env) => {
  const report        = []
  const subscriptions = await xm.subscriptions.getMany(env);

  await Promise.all(subscriptions.map(async sub => {
    let apps_and_lobs = xm.subscriptions.process_apps_and_lobs(sub.criteria.data);
    let sub_obj = {
      sub_name         : sub.name,
      sub_uuid         : sub.id,
      form_name        : sub.form.name,
      form_id          : sub.form.id,
      plan_name        : sub.form.plan.name,
      plan_id          : sub.form.plan.id,
      owner_targetName : sub.owner.targetName,
      owner_firstName  : sub.owner.firstName,
      owner_lastName   : sub.owner.lastName,
      owner_uuid       : sub.owner.id,
      applications     : apps_and_lobs.apps,
      lob              : apps_and_lobs.lobs
    };

    report.push(sub_obj);

    if (sub.recipients && sub.recipients.count > 1) {
      await (async (env) => {
        let recipients = await xm.subscriptions.getSubscribers(env, null, sub.id);
        recipients.map(r => {
          let recip_obj = {
            sub_name         : sub.name,
            sub_uuid         : sub.id,
            form_name        : sub.form.name,
            form_id          : sub.form.id,
            plan_name        : sub.form.plan.name,
            plan_id          : sub.form.plan.id,
            owner_targetName : r.targetName,
            owner_firstName  : r.firstName,
            owner_lastName   : r.lastName,
            owner_uuid       : r.id,
            applications     : apps_and_lobs.apps,
            lob              : apps_and_lobs.lobs
          };

          report.push(recip_obj);
          console.log(`> ${report.length}`);  // runs after the below COMPLETE > console log showing its breaking in async
        })
      })(env)
    } else {
      console.log(`> ${report.length}`);
    }
  })).then((thing) => {
    util.cmt(`COMPLETE > ${report.length}`);
    util.buildCSV(fields, report, 'subscriptions_dev', true);
  })
})(prod);
```

changed two lines:

```
await Promise.all(subscriptions.map(async sub => {


await (async (env) => {
```

Comment: YUR A WIZZARD HARRY. Thanks for fixing that buddy!!